# Is there official clarification how firbolg's Hidden Step interacts with delayed damage/save effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, invisibility, duration, firbolg

The playable Firbolg race from *Volo's Guide to Monsters* has the **Hidden Step** racial feature (emphasis mine):

> **Hidden Step**. As a bonus action, you can magically turn invisible until the start of your next turn or until you attack, **make a damage roll**, or **force someone to make a saving throw**. Once you use this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

I can see how the text says it works, but there are situations where its wording ends invisibility without you taking any offensive action. That's really unusual for invisibility effects.

(For example, the spell *Booming Blade* makes you make a damage roll for the spell later, but it's not you personally taking new offensive action: it deals damage when a previously-hit opponent moves before the caster's next turn.)

Therefore my question: **Have any errata or developer statements been made that clarify if “passive” delayed damage rolls or saving throws *aren't* meant to end Hidden Step?**

I'm specifically looking for official statements clarifying this exact kind of interaction. Interpretations based on the text aren't useful answers because I can already see how the interaction works absent errata, and speculation on the intention aren't official clarification.

I myself have been unable to find an official statement that clarifies this issue, only [this statement](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/11/19/its-intentional-that-a-firbolg-thats-invisible-from-hidden-step-can-cast-a-beneficial-spell-right/), which confirms that you are allowed to cast beneficial spells.

Comment: Outside of something like Booming Blade/Heat Metal/Witch Bolt, how would you roll for damage if not making an attack or forcing a saving throw? It seems like Rolling Damage is specifically for those types of events.

Comment: I'm certain that this spell is supposed to prevent Heat Metal, Witch Bolt, or Magic Missile, all of which take an action or bonus action and deal damage without an attack roll or saving throw. *Booming Blade*, however, requires no further action of any kind from you - it just *happens* when the affected creature moves.

Comment: @PixelMaster you care about the fact that the damage/effect is not a result of an action you took after using hidden step. Correct?

Comment: yes, based on how nearly all other kinds of invisibility work in the game. Also, I feel like *Booming Blade* is not exclusively an offensive spell, but also defensive (preventing your opponent from trying to come after you).

Comment: @PixelMaster It doesn't prevent your opponent from trying to come after you, it exacts a price for doing so.  Sort of like running through mud to come after you makes the shoes muddy, or running through lava to get at the fire elemental burns you ...

Comment: yeah, prevent was not the word I was looking for. More like "deter"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes, there is now an (un)official statement

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/959180348356681728) has clarified in a Tweet:

> Q: A firbolg PC casts booming blade then uses hidden step to go invisible. The creature that is hit with booming blade moves away and
> thus takes damage. Does hidden step deactivate?
>
> A: Hidden Step ends if you make a damage roll, no matter when you make
> it.
>
> Q: So it doesn't matter if a spell/effect is initiated by you before
> hidden step was activated? As long as you make a creature do a saving
> throw or attack or roll damage for any reason then hidden step ends?
>
> A: That's correct.

So, passive or not, as long as a creature is making a saving throw or taking damage from an effect you initiated (no matter when you initiated it) for any reason, *hidden step* will end.

This matches the intent we can understand when reading the ability itself.

#### Intent is clear from reading as well: if the user causes a harmful effect, *hidden step* deactivates.

The ability is explicitly written to restrict just about every way you can damage or harm an opponent (regardless of when said effect was initiated), so it seems clear that the intent was to prevent the user from doing harmful things. As such, allowing a loophole for spells and effects cast/initiated before the user used *hidden step* runs counter to that intent.

It may also be helpful to note that the designers also [intentionally wrote](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/959180348356681728) this ability so as not to restrict beneficial spells and abilities being used.

The ability is already quite powerful and from a DM standpoint this argument would seem like an attempt to cheese additional power out of the ability by circumventing its primary restrictions.

This also seems wholly fair. In the example of *booming blade*, the only reason to cast such a spell is to try to cause damage. If you also choose to use *hidden step* you are taking the risk that the opponent triggers that damage and thus cancels your ability. It was player choice to cast the spell and to use the ability.

#### Allowing this opens the door for plenty of bad things/cheese

Our heroic firbolgs casts *delayed blast fireball* at a group of 4 enemies, uses *hidden step*, then immediately stops concentrating on the spell. It takes no action to stop concentrating on a spell so this is the exact same scenario as with *booming blade*. This causes 4 saving throws and 4 creatures to take up to 12d6 damage.

Does it seem to be intended to allow such an effect to not break *hidden step*? This seems like an overtly harmful action and I really do not think for one second that the designers intended this to be the case.

And this is only a cursory look at one spell. I'm sure that there are many more and possibly even worse spells/effects one could get away with through this loophole.

**Neither RAW nor RAI support allowing a loophole for effects initiated before *hidden step* is activated.**

As always, a DM may, of course, allow this if they want to for any reason.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73967/discussion-on-answer-by-rubiksmoose-is-there-official-clarification-how-firbolg).

Comment: Crawford's tweets are no longer "official", but it's still useful unofficial guidance.